# MySQL: creation of in-memory copy of a Schema

Tags: mysql, database, memory

I am quite familiar with creation and destruction of temporary tables, however I can't seem to find anything in regard to creation of entire temporary (and in-memory) databases.

In my scenario, I need to create one or more temporary copies of an existing database, copying its structure only.

Is it even possible at all with My SQL?

Comment: You can create a schema and then delete it, when you don't need it any more.

Comment: @paul true, but I seem to understand that temporary tables are treated differently, being scoped to the session in which they are created. I could populate the schema with temporary tables but the schema itself wouldn't be "locally scoped". What I was wondering, if the same mechanism existed for entire session-scoped schemas.

Comment: I don't think there is something like that. However - If you really need that, there might be some workaround. E.g. You could use a random scheme name, which is stored in a session variable, and only known by the current session. Or you just use `CONNECTION_ID()` as part of the name. You can then write an *event* which will periodically clean up unused schemes.